# Ambiguous redirect with $@

Tags: bash, sudo

In `.profile` I have defined:

```
function fan.speed(){
    sudo su -c 'echo $@ > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1'
}
```

It throws the error:

```
$ fan.speed 100
bash: "$@": ambiguous redirect
```

When I use `""` instead of `''`, it works fine:

```
function fan.speed(){
    sudo su -c "echo $@ > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/pwm1"
}
```

What's wrong with `''`?

Comment: With single quotes you're sending the literal value `$@`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe : While it is clear that we need double quotes here, I wonder why the error message is _ambiguous redirect_.